# How many distinct composition series does the group $D_{12}$ have?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, dihedral-groups, solvable-groups

> How many distinct composition series does the group $D_{12}$ have?

I know that $D_{12}  \trianglerighteq \mathbb{Z}_6  \trianglerighteq \mathbb{Z}_3 \trianglerighteq \{e\}$ is a composition series ( as the elemebts in the series are of index $2$ and therefore therefore maximal, so the quotients must be simple).

Moreover, I know that the Jordan-Holder Theorem states that any two composition series have the same composition length and the same composition factors, up to permutation (reordering) and isomorphism.

Does it mean that the answer is $1$? Or that could be composition series of other length?

Comment: Leart to use computer! :) (GAP/Sagemath is free.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G = \langle x,y \mid x^6 = y^2 = (xy)^2 = 1 \rangle \cong D_{12}.$ So $x$ is a rotation of order $6$, and $y$ is a reflection. Then the four distinct composition series of $G$ are:
$$1.\ \ \ \ G > \langle x \rangle > \langle x^3 \rangle > 1; \ \ \ (D_{12} > C_6 >C_2 > 1)$$
$$2.\ \ \ \ G > \langle x \rangle > \langle x^2 \rangle > 1; \ \ \ (D_{12} > C_6 >C_3 > 1)$$
$$3.\ \ \ \ G > \langle x^2,y \rangle > \langle x^2 \rangle > 1; \ \ \ (D_{12} > D_6 >C_3 > 1)$$
$$4.\ \ \ \ G > \langle x^2,xy \rangle > \langle x^2 \rangle > 1; \ \ \ (D_{12} > D_6 >C_3 > 1)$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two others up to isomorphism.  I'm on my phone so I'm going to make typing easy.  In the series you give with $Z/6Z$ the top factor, you can also put $Z/2Z$ next.  There is also a series through $D_6$ and $Z/3Z$.  The top factor must have index 2, since an index 3 subgroup is 2-Sylow and not normal as there are 3 2-Sylows.  You can check that these are the only three possibilities.  However, since there are two $D_6$ subgroups, there are two series of that type related by an automorphism of $D_{12}$, as Derek Holt pointed out. So there are a total of four composition series.

Comment: But aren't those series isomorphic?

Comment: There are actually four altogether. Three with $Z/3Z$ at the bottom and one with $Z/2Z$.

Comment: Good point, as there are two $D_6$ in $D_{12}$.

Comment: @C Monsour So I understand that we get also $\mathbb{Z}_6 \trianglerighteq \mathbb{Z}_2 \trianglerighteq \{e\}$ but what does it mean that "there are two $D_6$ in $D_12$"?

Comment: It means that $D_{12}$ has (exactly) two subgroups that are isomorphic to $D_6$. If $D_{12} = \langle x,y \rangle$ with $x$ a rotation of order $6$ and $y$ a reflection, then those two subgroups are $\langle x^2,y \rangle$ and $\langle x^2,xy \rangle$.

Comment: @Derek Holt if they are all isomorphic to $D_6$, doesn't it mean (by Jordan theorem) that we should look at those as the same?

Comment: The question clearly asks for the number of *distinct* composition series. You should answer the question that is asked and not try and reinterpret it.

Comment: Maybe what is more interesting is that the other composition series don't have such doubles, which immediately implies that all subgroups in those series are characteristic, which immediately implies that they are chief series.  (The series through $D_6$ are also chief series, since $D_6$ is normal [though not characteristic].)

Comment: @Derek Holt So we get two $D_2$, one generated by $A=<x^2,y>$ and $B=<x^2,xy>$. Then, both $A,B$ go to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (as they can't have subgroup of order $3$) and we get another two distinct series?( Besides the one that I gave, and another one as like I gave but with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ instead of  $\mathbb{Z}_3$, giving us total of 4)